# What affects the time for a function to return to the caller.

Tags: c++, function

I measure the run time of two algorithms.

my main() function calls two algorithms and measures the time respectively.

Assume A() and B() are the names for the algorithms.

what I did was like (please ignore details here)

```
begin = 
A();
end = 
cout << "time A : " << end-begin << endl;
begin = 
B();
end = 
cout << "time B : " << end-begin << endl;
```

and I also measure the time inside of each function. 
for example,

```
A()
{
    begin = 
    .....
    end = 
    cout << "time inside A : " << end - begin << endl;
    return ..;
}
B()
{
    begin = 
    .....
    end = 
    cout << "time inside B : " << end - begin << endl;
    return ..;
}
```

It seems the time measuring in main() function and inside of A() function has very little difference. (like 150 milliseconds) 
but for the B(), it has more than 1500 milliseconds difference.

So, I would like to know what can affect this big difference between two functions call.

Comment: What are you returning? Big objects without move constructors by value?

Comment: "please ignore details here" ... code is all about details

Comment: Any computation or data access that you do can affect the speed of the code.  Please provide a  [mcve] and the exact output it gives.

Comment: Seeing as we have no idea what the code does or how, it could be affected by the airspeed of a swallow.

Comment: If there are any local variables with constructors or destructors, the time taken to run these functions will be included in the measurements in `main()`, but not inside the functions.

Comment: If you want to know where the time is being spent, use a profiler.

Comment: Look at the assembly language generated for your function.

Comment: Any RAII object destructor which will call code after `end =`.

Comment: @tobi303  you can see the code here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43240781/things-that-can-affect-time-taken-by-functions

Comment: @David Grayson you can see the code herehttps://stackoverflow.com/questions/43240781/things-that‌​-can-affect-time-tak‌​en-by-functions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The time returning from a function should be negligible.

Most processors have the instruction for returning from a function optimized, usually one instruction.

If you are returning an object via copy, the return time depends on the time required to copy the object.

Essentially, a return from function involves obtaining the return address, then setting the program counter to that address.  Not much time spent in returning.