# Things that can affect time taken by functions

Tags: c++, function

There is a set of points (say 100,000 points). What I try to do is

1. Find four extreme points (minimum x and y, maximum x and y)
2. Discard points inside of the first four extreme points
3. Find the next four extreme points among remaining points. (until there is no points left. in the code it stops when second four extreme points are found)

I implemented this in two ways.

First way : erase the points from the points set

Second way : only save the remaining points' index from the points set and use the index in order to find the next extreme points.

My problem is I measured the time taken by each algorithm (firstAlgorithm and secondAlgorithm) as shown in the codes and it seems secondAlgorithm takes less time than the first one. The result looks like

```
algorithm1 time taken until second equad found  105181
algorithm2 time taken until second equad found  63047
```

However, in main() function I call these two functions and measure the time taken by each and the result is

```
#include <iostream>
#include <random>
#include <chrono>
#include <fstream>
#include "Point.h"

bool isInside(Equads& eQuad, Point& p)
{
    if(orientation(eQuad.extremePoints[0], eQuad.extremePoints[1], p) < 0)
    {
      return false;
    }
    else if(orientation(eQuad.extremePoints[1], eQuad.extremePoints[2], p) < 0)
    {
      return false;
    }
    else if(orientation(eQuad.extremePoints[2], eQuad.extremePoints[3], p) < 0)
    {
      return false;
    }
    else if(orientation(eQuad.extremePoints[3], eQuad.extremePoints[0], p) < 0)
    {
      return false;
    }
    else
    {
      return true;
    }

}

void main()
{
    std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::time_point start;
    std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::time_point end;
    start = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    firstAlgorithm(points);
    end = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    std::cout << "compute time of firstAlgorithm (microseconds)" << chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::microseconds>(end - start).count() << std::endl;

    start = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    secondAlgorithm(points);
    end = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    std::cout << "compute time of secondAlgorithm (microseconds)" << chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::microseconds>(end - start).count() << std::endl;
}



compute time of firstAlgorithm (microseconds)  : 107282
compute time of secondAlgorithm (microseconds) : 142401
```

How come the secondAlgorithm becomes so slow when time is taken in the main() function?

Below is the code for the first way.

```
vector<Point> firstAlgorithm(vector<Point>& originalPoint)
{
    std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::time_point startTime;
    std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::time_point endTime;
    startTime = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();

    vector<Point> points = originalPoints;

    PointSequence result;
    Equads firstEquad; // Equads is array of points that store the four extreme points


    findExtremePoints1(points, firstEquad);

    Equads prev;
    prev = firstEquad;
    std::vector<Equads> eQuads;
    Equads current;

    int count = 0 ;

    while(findExtremePoints2(points, prev, current) != false)
    {
        eQuads.push_back(current);
        prev = current;

        if(count == 0) break;
    }
    endTime = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();

    std::cout << std::endl << "algorithm1 time taken until second equad found  " << std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::microseconds>(endTime - startTime).count() << std::endl;

    return result;
}
```

and findExtremePoints1 and findExtremePoints2 look like below

```
void findExtremePoints1(vector<Point>& points, Equads& eQuad)
{
  Point minX(points[0]),minY(points[0]),maxX(points[0]),maxY(points[0]);

  for(size_t i = 1; i < points.size(); i++)
  {
    if(points[i].x < minX.x)
    {
      minX = points[i];
    }
    if(points[i].x > maxX.x)
    {
      maxX = points[i];
    }
    if(points[i].y < minY.y)
    {
      minY = points[i];
    }
    if(points[i].y > maxY.y)
    {
      maxY = points[i];
    }
  }
  eQuad.extremePoints[0] = minX;
  eQuad.extremePoints[1] = minY;
  eQuad.extremePoints[2] = maxX;
  eQuad.extremePoints[3] = maxY;

  // erase the extreme points
  points.erase(remove(points.begin(),points.end(), eQuad.extremePoints[0]), points.end());
  points.erase(remove(points.begin(),points.end(), eQuad.extremePoints[1]), points.end());
  points.erase(remove(points.begin(),points.end(), eQuad.extremePoints[2]), points.end());
  points.erase(remove(points.begin(),points.end(), eQuad.extremePoints[3]), points.end());
}

// traverse the points and if any point is inside of previous equad(four extreme points) 
//then delete it from points set and if not inside find next four extreme points.
bool findExtremePoints2(vector<Point> points, Equads& prevEquad, Equads& eQuad)
{
  Point minX,minY,maxX,maxY;
  bool prevFound = false;
  std::vector<size_t> deletedVal;

  for(size_t i = 0; i < points.size(); i++)
  {
    if(isInside(prevEquad, points[i]))
    {
      deletedVal.push_back(i);
    }
    else
    {
      if(prevFound)
      {
        if(points[i].x < minX.x)
        {
          minX = points[i];
        }
        if(points[i].x > maxX.x)
        {
          maxX = points[i];
        }
        if(points[i].y < minY.y)
        {
          minY = points[i];
        }
        if(points[i].y > maxY.y)
        {
          maxY = points[i];
        }
      }
      else // not inside of the prev equad and the very first one. only meet this condition at very first time.
      {
        minX = points[i];
        minY = points[i];
        maxX = points[i];
        maxY = points[i];
        prevFound = true;
      }
    }
  }
  if (prevFound == false)
  {
    return false;
  }
  eQuad.extremePoints[0] = minX;
  eQuad.extremePoints[1] = minY;
  eQuad.extremePoints[2] = maxX;
  eQuad.extremePoints[3] = maxY;


  for(size_t i = deletedVal.size(); i-- > 0;)
  {
    points[deletedVal.at(i)] = points.back();
    points.pop_back();
  }

  // erase the extreme points
  points.erase(remove(points.begin(),points.end(), eQuad.extremePoints[0]), points.end());
  points.erase(remove(points.begin(),points.end(), eQuad.extremePoints[1]), points.end());
  points.erase(remove(points.begin(),points.end(), eQuad.extremePoints[2]), points.end());
  points.erase(remove(points.begin(),points.end(), eQuad.extremePoints[3]), points.end());

  return prevFound;
}
```

Below is for the code of second way.

```
vector<Point> secondAlgorithm(vector<Point>& points)
{

  std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::time_point startTime;
  std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::time_point endTime;

  startTime = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();

  vector<Point> result;
  std::vector<Equads> eQuads;
  Equads firstEquad;

  size_t sizeOfPoints = points.size();
  std::forward_list<size_t> remainedPoints;

  findExtremePointsAtFirst(points,firstEquad, sizeOfPoints);

  discardInsidePointsAtFirst(points,firstEquad,remainedPoints,sizeOfPoints);

  int count = 0 ;

  while(sizeOfPoints > 0)
  {
    Equads equads;
    findExtremePoints3(points, equads, remainedPoints, sizeOfPoints);
    eQuads.push_back(equads);
    if(count == 0 ) break;
  }

  endTime = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();

  std::cout << "algorithm2 time taken until second equad found  " << std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::microseconds>(endTime - startTime).count() << std::endl<< std::endl;
  return result;
}
```

and findExtremePointsAtFirst , discardInsidePointsAtFirst and findExtremePoints3 look like below.

```
void findExtremePointsAtFirst(vector<Point>& points, Equads& eQuad, size_t& sizeOfPoints)
{
  Point minX(points[0]),minY(points[0]),maxX(points[0]),maxY(points[0]);

  for(size_t i = 1; i < sizeOfPoints; i++)
  {
    if(points[i].x < minX.x)
    {
      minX = points[i];
    }
    if(points[i].x > maxX.x)
    {
      maxX = points[i];
    }
    if(points[i].y < minY.y)
    {
     minY = points[i];
    }
    if(points[i].y > maxY.y)
    {
      maxY = points[i];
    }
  }
  eQuad.extremePoints[0] = minX;
  eQuad.extremePoints[1] = minY;
  eQuad.extremePoints[2] = maxX;
  eQuad.extremePoints[3] = maxY;
} 

void discardInsidePointsAtFirst(vector<Point>& points, Equads& prevEquad, std::forward_list<size_t>& remainedPoints, size_t& sizeOfPoints)
{
  size_t remainedPointsSize = 0;
  for(size_t i = 0; i < points.size(); i++)
  {
    if(!isInside(prevEquad, points[i]))
    {
      remainedPoints.push_front(i+1);
      remainedPointsSize++;
    }
  }
  sizeOfPoints = remainedPointsSize;
} 

void findExtremePoints3(vector<Point>& points, Equads& eQuad, std::forward_list<size_t>& remainedPoints, size_t& sizeOfPoints)
{

  Point minX(points[remainedPoints.front()-1]);
  Point minY = minX, maxX = minX , maxY = minX;

  for(size_t i : remainedPoints)
  {
    i--;
    if(points[i].x < minX.x)
    {
      minX = points[i];
    }
    if(points[i].x > maxX.x)
    {
      maxX = points[i];
    }
    if(points[i].y < minY.y)
    {
      minY = points[i];
    }
    if(points[i].y > maxY.y)
    {
      maxY = points[i];
    }
  }

  eQuad.extremePoints[0] = minX;
  eQuad.extremePoints[1] = minY;
  eQuad.extremePoints[2] = maxX;
  eQuad.extremePoints[3] = maxY;
}
```

FYI

```
// Point.h file
    using CoordinateType = double;



struct Point
{
  CoordinateType x;
  CoordinateType y;

  // to find the leftmost point
  bool operator < (const Point& operand);
  bool operator ==(const Point& operand) const;
  Point& operator=(const Point& p);

  friend std::ostream& operator <<(std::ostream& os, const Point& p);

  bool isLower(const Point& p);
  bool isHigher(const Point& p);

  Point(CoordinateType x = -9999.0, CoordinateType y = -9999.0):x(x),y(y) {}
  Point(const Point& p) : x(p.x), y(p.y) {}
};

using PointSequence = std::vector<Point>;

int orientation(const Point& p, const Point& q, const Point& r);

struct Equads
{
  Point extremePoints[4]; // Xmin, Ymin, Xmax, Ymax order
  Equads& operator=(const Equads& e);
};

Equads& Equads::operator=(const Equads& e)
{
  std::copy(std::begin(e.extremePoints), std::end(e.extremePoints), std::begin(extremePoints));
  std::copy(std::begin(e.subRegions), std::end(e.subRegions), std::begin(subRegions));

  return *this;
}

// Point.cpp
#include "Point.h"

bool Point::operator <(const Point& operand)
{
  if(this->x < operand.x)
    return true;
  else if(this->x == operand.x && this->y < operand.y)
    return true;
  else
    return false;
}

bool Point::operator ==(const Point& operand) const
{
  if((this->x == operand.x) && (this->y == operand.y))
    return true;
  else
    return false;
}

Point& Point::operator=(const Point& p)
{
  x = p.x;
  y = p.y;

  return *this;
}
std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream& os, const Point& p)
{
  os << p.x << " , " << p.y << std::endl;
  return os;
}

bool Point::isLower(const Point& p)
{
  if(this->y < p.y)
  {
    return true;
  }
  else if(this->y == p.y && this->x < p.x)
  {
    return true;
  }
  return false;
}

bool Point::isHigher(const Point& p)
{
  if(this->y > p.y)
  {
    return true;
  }
  else if(this->y == p.y && this->x > p.x)
  {
    return true;
  }
  return false;
}

// to see if it turns clockwise or counterclockwise
int orientation(const Point& p, const Point& q, const Point& r)
{
  double val = (q.x - p.x) * (r.y - p.y) - (q.y - p.y) * (r.x - p.x);

  if (val == 0)
    return 0; // colinear
  return (val < 0) ? -1 : 1; // right or left

}
```

Comment: Your code has tons of undefined variables (like `points` and `start` in `main`) and you removed important `#include` directives.  Like I said last time, you should be providing an [mcve] so that someone can just copy and paste your code, compile it without having to mess around too much, and recreate your results.

Comment: @DavidGrayson Okay, I added more

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any local variables will be destroyed when they go out of scope (for variables that aren't declared inside loops or conditional blocks, that happens when your function returns); if any of those are complex types (e.g. `struct`/`class` instances not hidden behind pointers or references), their [destructors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Destructor_%28computer_programming%29#In_C.2B.2B) will be executed, which may take extra time.

In this case, you have vectors of `Point` and `Equads` objects, each of which may need to have its destructor called. Your first algorithm is erasing elements from its `points` vector as it goes along (increasing the total run time within the function, but reducing the cleanup when it exits), while your second algorithm does not (making it run faster but take longer to cleanup).